# Собственные модули C++

Tags: c++, dll, плагин

скажите, загорелся написать модульную программу на c++, где функциональность будет расширяться в зависимости от того, какие модули были загружены программой. (скажем, если модули лежат в папке "/modules", то они загружаются)

Писал и раньше такое, но, использовал для этого .dll библиотеки, однако, хочу написать собстенный контейнер (можно это все впихнуть в .dll, но хочу свое, без использования Qt и тд).

**Требуется**: файл(он же модуль) представляет из себя контейнер, в котором находятся новые классы, их описание, карртинки, и тд). (понятное дело будет таблица с адрессами, где все содержится), который в процессе работы программы будет загружатся, создавать экземлпяры классов (о которых программа ничего не должна знать, кроме как общие интерфейсы, например) и добавляться в основной цикл программы. Те, все тоже самое что и dll, только своего формата.

Возможно ли такое реализовать? В с++ нет рефлексии, на Джава, такое реализовать бы не составило большого труда, но, а что делать с с++? Если возможно, дайте пожалукйста совет/ссылку в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79036/discussion-on-question-by-valery---c).